# How does IntelliJ create artifacts from pom files?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

We have a large project that uses Maven. I don't use `mvn idea:idea`, I just open the maven project in IntelliJ and the majority of the work is done in terms of setting up the artifacts.

Some of the artifact settings I need to do manually as the artifact set up in IntelliJ is not identical to the one created when I run `mvn clean install` from the command line. Every time there is a change to the pom file I need to reapply these manual settings. (It's settings for an EJB and and EAR artifact if that changes things.)

Is there any way of getting IntelliJ to do these steps for me automatically? Or is there an article that I can read about how IntelliJ generates it's artifact settings from the pom files?

Thanks in advance :)

[EDIT]

Just to be clear, the pom file is already being automatically imported when there are changes to it. It's the manual changes that I applied after the previous import that are lost that I would like to find out how to automatically restore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from version 10.0, IDEA can be set up so to perform re-import of changes in POM files automatically.

Comment: The re-importing of the POM file is already happening. When this happens, any manual changes since the last import of the pom file are lost and it's these manual changes that I'd like to find out more about.

Comment: Ah, yes. This behavior cannot be overridden, I guess. What manual changes do you perform? I've made a dozen of project with this feature and never needed any manual intervention.

Comment: One of the problems is that when the EJB artifact is made, all of the third-party jars land up in the output folder instead of no third-party jars and a manifest file which is what I need. Should I be using the pom to control this?

Comment: @Rachel, seems like you have some dependency issues in you POM file

Comment: Ok. I'll take a closer look at that pom file and see what I find. Thanks :)